# How to transform a subfolder into a subrepository?

Tags: mercurial

I have a subfolder in my repo that I want to extract into a subrepo. The problem is that you have to commit deletion of all the files in that folder from the original repo, that will create issues when trying to update to an earlier revision. Furthermore, if you have inited a subrepo first, added it to `.hgsub`, and only then commit deletion of the original files, it will also delete them from the subrepo (a bit confusing).

Is there a better way to tell Mercurial that the files have moved to a subrepo, unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to preserving sanity here is Mercurial’s `convert` functionality. The basic approach has been summarized at http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/ as follows:

> Converting Folder Into a Subrepository
>
> A project might contain a folder with some code, which at a later point is realized should be used across different projects. This code could of course just be copied to a repository, which the projects could include as subrepository. This would however mean that we would loose our precious history of these files.
>
> The way to do it, is by converting a folder into a repository, using the convert extension and then include this repository as a subrepository in the different projects.

Further details are given on the cited page, as well as at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension

If it is an option, then you might consider using `convert` twice, to split the original repo into two - one including the selected files (with their histories), and the other excluding them.

#### Illustrative transcript (invoking `convert` just once)

```
/tmp$ mkdir repo
/tmp$ cd repo
/tmp/repo$ hg init
/tmp/repo$ echo a > a.txt
/tmp/repo$ mkdir folder
/tmp/repo$ echo b > folder/b.txt
/tmp/repo$ hg addremove
hg addremove
adding a.txt
adding folder/b.txt
/tmp/repo$ hg commit -m init
/tmp/repo$ (echo include folder; echo rename folder .) > map.txt
/tmp/repo$ hg convert --filemap map.txt . subrepo
initializing destination subrepo repository
scanning source...
sorting...
converting...
0 init
/tmp/repo$ cd subrepo
/tmp/repo/subrepo$ hg update
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
/tmp/repo/subrepo$ find .
.
./b.txt
./.hg
<etc>
/tmp/repo/subrepo$ cd ..
/tmp/repo$ hg rm folder/b.txt
/tmp/repo$ file folder
file folder
folder: cannot open `folder' (No such file or directory)
/tmp/repo$ ls
a.txt   map.txt subrepo
/tmp/repo$ mv subrepo folder
/tmp/repo$ echo folder = folder > .hgsub
/tmp/repo$ hg add .hgsub
/tmp/repo$ hg st -dram
hg st -dram
A .hgsub
R folder/b.txt
/tmp/repo$ hg commit -m 'subrepo created'
/tmp/repo$ hg files
hg files
.hgsub
.hgsubstate
a.txt
/tmp/repo$ cd folder
/tmp/repo/folder$ hg files
hg files
b.txt
/tmp/repo/folder$ echo c >> b.txt
echo c >> b.txt
/tmp/repo/folder$ cat b.txt
cat b.txt
b
c
/tmp/repo/folder$ hg commit -m "modified c"
hg commit -m "modified c"
/tmp/repo/folder$ cd ..
cd ..
/tmp/repo$ hg files --rev 0
hg files --rev 0
a.txt
folder/b.txt
/tmp/repo$ hg co --rev 0
hg co --rev 0
abort: path 'folder/b.txt' is inside nested repo 'folder'
/tmp/repo$ hg cat --rev 0 folder/b.txt
hg cat --rev 0 folder/b.txt
b
/tmp/repo$ hg -R folder cat --rev 0 folder/b.txt
hg -R folder cat --rev 0 folder/b.txt
b
/tmp/repo$ hg -R folder cat --rev 1 folder/b.txt
hg -R folder cat --rev 1 folder/b.txt
b
c
/tmp/repo$
```

Comment: Thanks! That will definitely come in handy, although it only solves half the problem. It does extract files into a subrepo, preserving changesets. But it does not prevent chaos from ensuing in the parent repo. For each file in the new subrepo, `hg status` reports that it had been deleted. Attempts to do anything with these files, like `forget` them, result in: `abort: path "so and so" is inside nested repo "new-subrepo"`. Any ideas how that might be circumvented?

Comment: First, as I said, if it were my repo, I'd probably want to split it into two, as mentioned in the last para of my post.  Second, I think you might be doing things in the wrong order. I'll append a transcript illustrating that things really do work quite nicely.  In particular, notice that after the "convert", it is possible to view (i.e. cat) the file b.txt as it was in a prior state in the top-level folder, but it's not possible to "check it out" from the top-level repo, because hg recognizes the conflict.

Comment: Odd, that's pretty much what I've tried and it doesn't work that way.

Comment: “Doesn’t” or “ didn’t”?  There’s more than one way to do this, but it’s also easy to try to do things in the wrong order ....